# Laravel - Paypal user to user money transfer

Tags: laravel, vue.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i have a donation website where users post their cases and any other user can donate to them, i want to implement paypal integration but my question is what do i write in the paypal clientid and secret key if the receipient is different for each case? every tutorial i see, it has a fixed receipient so they just write the clientid of their merchant account, but in my website there is no fixed receipient as each user that posts a case can receive donations.

sorry if my question is too basic but this is my first time working with paypal. any help is really appreciated!

Comment: What most sites that do this do is either (a) take the money from the user donating, and then send an equal (almost) amount to the user receiving the donation essentially acting as an intermediary  (b) publish the PayPal information of the user that will be receiving the donation so anyone who wants to donate can do so directly via PayPal essentially acting as a forum. Not sure if these are the only ways though.

Answer (score 0):

For payments directly to another account, there are two different integration options:

1. **Checkout flow** :: specify the `payee.email_address` of the recipient's PayPal account when creating the order. See [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/).
2. **Donation flow** :: specify the recipient account as the `business` parameter. See [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/donate/). Do not specify a `hosted_button_id`. Specifying a fixed `amt` is optional.